# German app with example sentences by word

Tags: resource

There is an excellent Japanese learning app called Kanji Study. One great thing about it is that it has a function where you can search a word and see, generally, lots of example sentences, among other information.

This question: [Dictionaries with example sentences for each entry](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18825/dictionaries-with-example-sentences-for-each-entry) indicates that there are various sources but they seem to be split between definition and example sentences.

Closest thing seems to be [dreiartikel](https://dreiartikel.com/dictionary?q=verbindung&d=de), is there anything else?

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. So do I understand you correctly that you are looking for an app/ webpage where you can enter a german word and get lots of example sentences with it? And unlike the answers to your found question you're looking for both examples AND dictionary into one?

Answer (score 1):

https://tatoeba.org/ (also) has German example sentences (with English meaning).

Answer (score -1):

With  [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com)  free mobile app or web and a few minutes a day, everyone can Duolingo. Learn 30+ languages online with bite-size lessons based on science.

Duolingo basic learning is sentence-based and teaches all the grammar and vocabulary in the sentence.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Unfortunately, you do miss any examples why "Duolingo" fits the needs of OP. For me your answer just reads as advertisement.  Please consider a description why this platform does what OP asked.

Comment: Duolingo basic learning is sentence-based and teaches all the grammar and vocabulary in the sentence